# Ending an input stream with a specified character, such as '|'?

Tags: c++, input, iostream

Currently learning C++, newbie.

I have an issue when ending the input with the '|' character, my program skips to the end/ends and does not allow for further input. I believe it is because std::cin is in an error state due to inputting a char when expecting an int, so i have tried to use std::cin.clear() and std::cin.ignore() to clear the issue and allow the remainder of the programme to run but I still cannot seem to crack it, any advice appreciated.

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> numbers{};
    int input{};
    char endWith{ '|' };

    std::cout << "please enter some integers and press " << endWith << " to stop!\n";
    while (std::cin >> input)
    {
        if (std::cin >> input)
        {
            numbers.push_back(input);
        }
        else
        {
            std::cin.clear();
            std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max());
        }
    }
```

And then pass the vector to a function to iterate through x amount of times and add each element to a total, but the program always skips past the user input:

```
std::cout << "Enter the amount of integers you want to sum!\n";
    int x{};
    int total{};
    std::cin >> x;


    for (int i{ 0 }; i < x; ++i)
    {
        total += print[i];
    }

    std::cout << "The total of the first " << x << " numbers is " << total;
```

Please help!

Comment: istream.getline() has an optional delimiter char: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/basic_istream/getline/

Comment: `std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max());` should be `std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the use enters a "|" (or anything that is not an `int`), the loop ends and the error handling that is inside the loop does not execute. Just move the error code to outside the loop. Also, you read from `stdin` twice which will skip every other int.

```
while (std::cin >> input) {
    numbers.push_back(input);
}
std::cin.clear();
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```

Note: If you want to specifically check for "|" can change to something like this:

```
while (true) {
    if (std::cin >> input) {
        numbers.push_back(input);
    }
    else {
        // Clear error state
        std::cin.clear();
        char c;
        // Read single char
        std::cin >> c;
        if (c == '|') break;
        // else what to do if it is not an int or "|"??
    }
}
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
```